# Unir array por key y value PHP

Tags: php, array

Que tal como estan todos, quiero juntar valores que sean iguales y de la misma manera con las keys.

Probe un foreach, para juntar a todos los que tenian el mismo nombre, no existe mucho problema con eso, el tema viene cuando quiero juntar `house` y `color`, ya que puede haber varios `color` en una `house` y a su vez un nombre puede tener varias `house`.

Como ejemplo tengo este array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jhon
        [lastname] => Lex
        [country] => AR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => De las Flores
        [color] => Verde
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jhon
        [lastname] => Lex
        [country] => AR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Ricasldo
        [color] => Azul
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jhon
        [lastname] => Lex
        [country] => AR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Ricasldo
        [color] => Rojo
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jhon
        [lastname] => Lex
        [country] => AR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Ricasldo
        [color] => Negro
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Nick
        [lastname] => Marcos
        [country] => BR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Velarde
        [color] => Amarillo
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Nick
        [lastname] => Marcos
        [country] => BR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Patron
        [color] => Rojo
    )
```

Lo que quiero lograr es algo como esto:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jhon
        [lastname] => Lex
        [country] => AR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Array
           (

            [De las Flores] => Verde

            [Ricasldo] => Array
                    (
                        [color] => Array
                            (

                                [0] => Azul

                                [1] => Rojo

                                [2] => Negro
                            )
                    )
           )
   )


[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Nick
        [lastname] => Marcos
        [country] => BR
        [city] => XX
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
        [house] => Array
        (

            [Velarde] => Amarillo

            [Patron] => Rojo

        )
   )
```

No tiene que ser exactamente igual, seria genial, si se pudiera lanzar ideas.
Hasta el momento eh usado esto:

```
  function getAllData($stmt) {
    $prueba = array();

    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($row as $item) {
        if (!isset($prueba[$item['name']]['house'])) {

            $prueba[$item['name']] = array('name'=> $item['name'],
                                            'lastname' => $item['lastname'],
                                            'country' =>  $item['country'],
                                            'city' =>  $item['city'],
                                            'description' =>  $item['description'],
                                            'image' =>  $item['image'],
                                            'house' => array($item['house'] => $item['color']));


                       }
    }
    return array_values($prueba);
}
```

y esto me devuelve:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [name] => Jhon
    [lastname] => Lex
    [country] => AR
    [city] => XX
    [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
    [house] => Array
        (
            [De las Flores] => Verde
        )

)

[1] => Array
(
    [name] => Nick
    [lastname] => Marcos
    [country] => BR
    [city] => XX
    [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    [image] => https://i.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
    [house] => Array
        (
            [Velarde] => Amarillo
        )

)
```

En la parte de `house` y `color` coje el primer dato de ambos. Aqui supongo que lo mas logico seria hacer otro foreach especialmente para `house` y `color` , el tema esta en que no se me viene como hacerlo sin romper todo. Pero recurri aqui jajaja para ver si alguien tiene una idea, o quizas una solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
// definimos un arreglo
$final = [];
// recorremos las posiciones del arreglo
for($i =0; $i < count($data);$i++) {
    // ahora reccorremos cada key del arreglo
    foreach ($data[$i] as $key => $value) {
        // validamos si la llave no existe en el arreglo final
         if (!array_key_exists($key,$final)) {
            // si no existe la creamos y le asignamos un el primer valor en forma de arreglo
            $final[$key][] = $value;
         }else{
            // en caso de que ya exista
            // validamos que el valor este en el arreglo para evitar duplicados
        // se puede remove el condicional en caso de querer valores repetidos
            if(!in_array($value,$final[$key])){
                // si no existe agregamos el valor a la llave especifica
                $final[$key][]=$value;
            }
         }
    }
}

// imprimimos para comprovar el resultado
print_r($final);
```